# How to make better performance withparameter in where which can be null?

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables :

```
CREATE TABLE `branches` (
  `id` smallint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `new_meeting_expire_days` tinyint unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `country` varchar(2) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `state_id` smallint unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `slug` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `branches_name_unique` (`name`),
  UNIQUE KEY `branches_slug_unique` (`slug`),
  KEY `branches_branch_id_state_id_active_index` (`country`,`state_id`,`active`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

AND

```
CREATE TABLE `departments` (
  `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `branch_id` smallint unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `manager_id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `departments_name_unique` (`name`),
  KEY `departments_manager_id_foreign` (`manager_id`),
  KEY `departments_branch_id_manager_id_name_index` (`branch_id`,`manager_id`,`name`),
  CONSTRAINT `departments_branch_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`branch_id`) REFERENCES `branches` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `departments_manager_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`manager_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Making request :

```
explain format=tree    SELECT id, name, branch_id
FROM departments
WHERE (1 IS NULL OR branch_id = 1)
```

I see that index departments_branch_id_manager_id_name_index is used:

```
-> Limit: 200 row(s)  (cost=0.8 rows=5)
-> Covering index lookup on departments using departments_branch_id_manager_id_name_index (branch_id=1)  (cost=0.8 rows=5)
```

But my question as I use where block :

```
WHERE (1 IS NULL OR branch_id = 1)
```

Value "1" is actually a parameter into stored procedure - it can be null
I wonder is it a good way to set filter in this way ? Other better decision ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would be useful if you posted the relevant parts of the sp and explained what you are trying to achieve,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT id, name, branch_id
    FROM departments
    WHERE (1 IS NULL OR branch_id = 1);
SHOW WARNINGs;
```

You will probably find that the `1 IS NULL OR` has been removed.  This is because of a simple "constant evaluation" during the Optimization phase.

Comment: No warnings on commands :

` explain format=tree    SELECT id, name, branch_id
FROM departments
WHERE (1 IS NULL OR branch_id = 1);

SHOW WARNINGS;
`
Only output :
`-> Limit: 200 row(s)  (cost=0.8 rows=5)
    -> Covering index lookup on departments using departments_branch_id_manager_id_name_index (branch_id=1)  (cost=0.8 rows=5)
`

Comment: Plain `EXPLAIN`, not `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`.